# Inconsistent JSON parsing through IOptions .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm building a Component that parse the appsettings that contains the sitemap and query to database to display the sidemenu.

I've bumped into a weird consistency error with the IOption pattern. It works fine on the first load but sometime the appsettings object is incomplete and my menu isn't rendered properly

I'm created a static class that fits my AppSettings. I registered it in the startup class. I don't think this is the issue since on first start the object is filled properly.

The component is called at each page load and rendered from the _Layout view

**sitemap object successfully binded**
[image: sitemap object successfully binded]

**After two page load, childrens are missing from one node**
[image: After two page load, childrens are missing from one node]

How is it possible that does value change ?
The appsettings doesn't change at all

In case this is my model class

```
 public class SiteMap
{
    public List<SiteMapNode> Nodes { get; set; }
}
public class SiteMapNode
{
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public int PrestationCount { get; set; }
    public List<SiteMapNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that I think parse the appsettings on startup
`builder.Services.Configure<SiteMap>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SiteMap"));`

Here is a part of my appsettings

```
{
...
  "SiteMap": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "ResourceName": "Accueil",
        "Href": "/",
        "Icon": "fas fa-home",
        "Roles": "*",
        "Children": null
      },
      {
        "ResourceName": "MonProfil",
        "Href": "--dropdown",
        "Icon": "flaticon2-user",
        "Roles": "*",
        "Children": [
          {
            "ResourceName": "Parametres",
            "Href": "--dropdown",
            "Icon": "flaticon2-settings",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": [
              {
                "ResourceName": "CorrigerAdresse",
                "Href": "/account/address-error",
                "Icon": "fas fa-map-marker-alt",
                "Roles": "*",
                "Children": null
              },
              {
                "ResourceName": "AnnoncerDemenagement",
                "Href": "/account/relocation",
                "Icon": "fas fa-house-user",
                "Roles": "*",
                "Children": null
              },
              {
                "ResourceName": "ChangementTitulaire",
                "Href": "/account/ownership",
                "Icon": "fas fa-user-edit",
                "Roles": "*",
                "Children": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "Factures",
            "Href": "/invoices",
            "Icon": "flaticon-layer",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "ModeFacturation",
            "Href": "/account/billing",
            "Icon": "fas fa-file-invoice-dollar",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "ChangerMotDePasse",
            "Href": "/account/change-password",
            "Icon": "fas fa-key",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ResourceName": "MesPrestations",
        "Href": "--dropdown",
        "Icon": "fas fa-box-open",
        "Roles": "*",
        "Children": [
          {
            "ResourceName": "TelephonieInternet",
            "Href": "/prestation/voip",
            "Icon": "flaticon2-phone",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "Mobile",
            "Href": "/prestation/mobile",
            "Icon": "fa fa-mobile",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "ConnexionInternet",
            "Href": "/prestation/internet",
            "Icon": "flaticon2-world",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "MyCanal",
            "Href": "/prestation/tv",
            "Icon": "fas fa-tv",
            "Roles": "*",
            "Children": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ResourceName": "Partenaire",
        "Href": "--dropdown",
        "Icon": "far fa-handshake",
        "Roles": "partner",
        "Children": [
          {
            "ResourceName": "Clients",
            "Href": "/partner/clients",
            "Icon": "flaticon-users-1",
            "Roles": "partner",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "StatistiquesParJour",
            "Href": "/partner/daily-stats",
            "Icon": "flaticon2-pie-chart-1",
            "Roles": "partner",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "StatistiquesParClient",
            "Href": "/partner/client-stats",
            "Icon": "fas fa-chart-bar",
            "Roles": "partner",
            "Children": null
          },
          {
            "ResourceName": "Documentation",
            "Href": "/partner/documentation",
            "Icon": "flaticon2-open-text-book",
            "Roles": "partner",
            "Children": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone got an idea or a simlar problem ?

Comment: `IOptions` doesn't parse anything. The configuration settings were loaded when the host was created. Post your configuration data and code *as text*

Comment: Okay sorry, I added up the JSON in my appsettings and the code at startup.